# Cannot invoke "com.example.demo.entities.Vacation.add(com.example.demo.entities.CartItem)" because "vacation" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I get a Cannot invoke "com.example.demo.entities.Vacation.add(com.example.demo.entities.CartItem)" because "vacation" is null error when I run my spring boot maven app

My Cart.java file

```
package com.example.demo.entities;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Entity
@Table(name = "carts")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Cart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cart_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "order_tracking_number")
    private String orderTrackingNumber;

    @Column(name = "package_price")
    private BigDecimal package_price;

    @Column(name = "party_size")
    private int party_size;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private StatusType status;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date create_date;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Date last_update;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cart")
    private Set<CartItem> cartItems = new HashSet<>();

    public void add(CartItem cartItem){
        if (cartItem!= null) {
            if (cartItems == null) {
                cartItems = new HashSet<>();
            }
            cartItems.add(cartItem);
            cartItem.setCart(this);
        }
    }
}
```

My CartItem.java file

```
package com.example.demo.entities;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import java.util.*;

@Entity@Table(name = "cart_items")
@Getter
@Setter
public class CartItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cart_item_id")
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date create_date;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Date last_update;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id", nullable = false)
    private Cart cart;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vacation_id", nullable = false)
    private Vacation vacation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cartItem")
    Set<ExcursionCartItem> excursionCartItems = new HashSet<>();    

    public void add(ExcursionCartItem excursionCartItem) {
        if (excursionCartItem != null) {
            if (excursionCartItems == null) {
                excursionCartItems = new HashSet<>();
            }
            excursionCartItems.add(excursionCartItem);
            excursionCartItem.setCartItem(this);
        }
    }
}
```

My Excursion.java file

```
package com.example.demo.entities;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Entity
@Table(name = "excursions")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Excursion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "excursion_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "excursion_title")
    private String excursion_title;

    @Column(name = "excursion_price")
    private BigDecimal excursion_price;

    @Column(name = "image_URL")
    private String image_URL;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date create_date;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Date last_update;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vacation_id", nullable = false)
    private Vacation vacation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "excursion")
    Set<ExcursionCartItem> excursionCartItems = new HashSet<>();

    public void add(ExcursionCartItem excursionCartItem) {
        if (excursionCartItem != null) {
            if (excursionCartItems == null) {
                excursionCartItems = new HashSet<>();
            }
            excursionCartItems.add(excursionCartItem);
            excursionCartItem.setExcursion(this);
        }
    }
}
```

My ExcursionCartItem.java file

```
package com.example.demo.entities;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "excursion_cartitem")
public class ExcursionCartItem {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ExcursionCartItemKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("cartItemId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_item_id")
    CartItem cartItem;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("excursionId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "excursion_id")
    Excursion excursion;
}
```

My ExcursionCartItemKey.java file

```
package com.example.demo.entities;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
public class ExcursionCartItemKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "cart_item_id")
    Long cart_item_id;

    @Column(name = "excursion_id")
    Long excursion_id;

    //@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "cart_item_id")
    //@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //@MapsId("cart_item_id")
    //private CartItem cartItem;

    //@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //@MapsId("excursion_id")
    //private Excursion excursion;

    //@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "excursion_id")
    //private Excursion excursion;
}
```

My Vacation.java file

```
package com.example.demo.entities;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "vacations")
@Getter
@Setterpublic class Vacation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "vacation_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "vacation_title")
    private String vacation_title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "travel_fare_price")
    private Double travel_price;

    @Column(name = "image_URL")
    private String image_URL;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date create_date;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Date last_update;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "vacation")
    private Set<CartItem> cartItems = new HashSet<>(); 

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "vacation")
    private Set<Excursion> excursions = new HashSet<>();

    public void add(CartItem cartItem){
        if (cartItem!= null) {
            if (cartItems == null) {
                cartItems = new HashSet<>();
            }
            cartItems.add(cartItem);
            cartItem.setVacation(this);
        }
    }
}
```

My Purchase.java file

```
package com.example.demo.services;
import com.example.demo.entities.*;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.Getter;
import java.util.Set;

@Setter
@Getter
public class Purchase {    
    private Customer customer;    
    private Cart cart;    
    private CartItem cartItem;    
    private ExcursionCartItem excursionCartItem;    
    private Excursion excursion;
    private Vacation vacation;
    private Set<CartItem> cartItems;
    private Set<ExcursionCartItem> excursionCartItems;
}
```

My PurchaseResponse.java file

```
package com.example.demo.services;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
@Setter@Getterpublic class PurchaseResponse {
    private final String orderTrackingNumber;

    public PurchaseResponse(String orderTrackingNumber) {
        this.orderTrackingNumber = orderTrackingNumber;
    }
}
```

My CheckoutService.java file

```
package com.example.demo.services;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@CrossOrigin
public interface CheckoutService {
    PurchaseResponse placeOrder(Purchase purchase);
}
```

My CheckoutServiceImpl.java file

```
package com.example.demo.services;
import com.example.demo.dao.CartRepository;
import com.example.demo.dao.ExcursionCartItemRepository;
import com.example.demo.dao.VacationRepository;
import com.example.demo.entities.*;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.Set;import java.util.UUID;

@Service
public class CheckoutServiceImpl implements CheckoutService{
    @Autowired

    private CartRepository cartRepository;
    @Autowired
    public CheckoutServiceImpl(CartRepository cartRepository) {
        this.cartRepository = cartRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public PurchaseResponse placeOrder(Purchase purchase) {
        // retrieve the cart info from entity
        Cart cart = purchase.getCart();
        CartItem cartItem = purchase.getCartItem();
        ExcursionCartItem excursionCartItem = purchase.getExcursionCartItem();
        Excursion excursion = purchase.getExcursion();
        Vacation vacation = purchase.getVacation();

        // generate tracking number
        String orderTrackingNumber = generateOrderTrackingNumber();
        cart.setOrderTrackingNumber(orderTrackingNumber);
        cart.setStatus(StatusType.ordered);

        // populate cart with cartItems
        Set<CartItem> cartItems = purchase.getCartItems();
        cartItems.forEach(item -> cart.add(item));
        cartItems.forEach(item -> vacation.add(item));

        Set<ExcursionCartItem> excursionCartItems = purchase.getExcursionCartItems();
        excursionCartItems.forEach(item -> cartItem.add(item));
        excursionCartItems.forEach(item -> excursion.add(item));
        cartRepository.save(cart);

        // return a response
        return new PurchaseResponse(orderTrackingNumber);
    }

    private String generateOrderTrackingNumber() {
        // generate a random UUID number
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

Table structure

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `full-stack-ecommerce`;
CREATE DATABASE `full-stack-ecommerce`;
USE `full-stack-ecommerce`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `countries`;
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
    `country_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `create_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_update` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `vacations`;
CREATE TABLE `vacations` (
    `vacation_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `create_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `image_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_update` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `travel_fare_price` decimal(19, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `vacation_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`vacation_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `divisions`;
CREATE TABLE `divisions` (
    `division` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `division_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `create_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_update` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `country_id` bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`division_id`),
    KEY (`country_id`),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`country_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `excursions`;
CREATE TABLE `excursions` (
    `excursion_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `create_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `excursion_price` decimal(19, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `excursion_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `image_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_update` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `vacation_id` bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`excursion_id`),
    KEY (`vacation_id`),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`vacation_id`) REFERENCES `vacations` (`vacation_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customers`;
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
    `customer_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `create_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `customer_first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `customer_last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_update` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `postal_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `division_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`),
    KEY (`division_id`),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`division_id`) REFERENCES `divisions` (`division_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `carts`;
CREATE TABLE `carts` (
    `cart_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `package_price` decimal(19, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `party_size` int DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` ENUM ('pending', 'ordered', 'canceled'),
    `order_tracking_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `create_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_update` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `customer_id` bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`cart_id`),
    KEY (`customer_id`),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cart_items`;
CREATE TABLE `cart_items` (
    `cart_item_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `create_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_update` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cart_id` bigint NOT NULL,
    `vacation_id` bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`cart_item_id`),
    KEY (`cart_id`),
    KEY (`vacation_id`),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`vacation_id`) REFERENCES `vacations` (`vacation_id`),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`cart_id`) REFERENCES `carts` (`cart_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `excursion_cartitem`;
CREATE TABLE `excursion_cartitem` (
    `cart_item_id` bigint NOT NULL,
    `excursion_id` bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`cart_item_id`, `excursion_id`),
    KEY (`excursion_id`),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`cart_item_id`) REFERENCES `cart_items` (`cart_item_id`),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`excursion_id`) REFERENCES `excursions` (`excursion_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I was expecting it to insert into three tables :carts, cart_items, excursion_cartitem

Comment: Please format your code correctly and include the full stack trace.

Comment: Updating it shortly

Comment: You must include the full stack trace.